# unable to hit the spring controller when tested in IE11

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I have a trouble with IE when ng-click is used in the button.
I want to reload the data from spring controller whenever user click on the button which is working fine in chrome but not in IE11. 
Issue is when page is loaded data is displayed on the webpage, when Refresh Data button is clicked, it will reload the data by hitting to the spring controller which is not working in IE. In IE, when user click on a button, it is hitting the angular controller as well as service method also but not hitting the spring controller.But when developer tools is opened it is hitting the spring controller.

Example below:
html code:

```
    <div ng-controller="loadingSampleCtrl">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="loadOrRefreshData()">Reload</button>
{{myData.empName}} /* This is printed in chrome as well as in IE with developer tools opened*/
    </div>
```

js code:

```
myApp.controller('loadingSampleCtrl', function ($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.loadData = function () {
    $scope.loading = true;
       MyService.testData().then(
            function (response) {
                alert("response back from spring controllerf");
                if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
                    $scope.IEBrowser = true;
                    $scope.myData = response;
                    /* $timeout(function() {
                     $scope.pdfName = response;
                     }, 0);*/
                } else {
                    $scope.IEBrowser = false;
                     $scope.myData = response;
                }
            },
            function (errResponse) {
                $rootScope.showError("Internal error" + errResponse);
            });
    }
    $scope.testData();
});

//service call
    _myService.testData = function(){
          alert("service call");//this alert is visible in IE
           var deferred = $q.defer();
        var repUrl = myAppURL+'/myDataToRead/getData.form';
        $http.get(repUrl).then(
                function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function(errResponse){

                    deferred.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

spring controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<String> getMyData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In MyDataController"); //not printed in IE when tested without developer tools
    //logic here
    //return statement
}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: any one faced the same issue as above before????

Comment: Did not understand why the URL created in `service` is not matching with the `@RequestMapping` declared for Spring controller. The URL should be something like `var repUrl = myAppURL + '/getData';`. Also check in IE developer tools about the error logged when invoking the spring controller

Answer (score 0):

i check you url `var repUrl = yAppURL+'/myDataToRead/getData.form';`, and i this the issue is you are not map controller with the path. you are only map your method with `/getData`. you need to use `@RequestMapping` annotation into your controller. you can refer below code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myDataToRead")
```